# send data to and receive data from server using react, php and xampp

Tags: php, reactjs, xampp

I am currently going through react course and practising using one of my earlier projects developed with jquery and php for backend. I use XAMPP localhost. So far everthing works fine.
Concerning reactjs, my concern is this. At the moment I use jquery $.post() and php file to communicate with my XAMPP database. An example is this:

```
$.post('php/get_user_profiles_using_password.php', {password:
     enteredCurrentPassword}, (data) => { 
}).done((data) => {
     console.log(data);
     // do some things 
}).fail((xhr) => {
    alert(`An error ${xhr.statusText} has occurred. Please try later`); 
});
```

Sometimes I put the above code in useEffect(), setTimeout(), or use try & catch method depending on the need.
So far this works well. But is this a good practise?

Now I have read about using promise, e.g fetch().then() or async, await But I do not know how to send the user data (e.g password as above), php file to the server and receive corresponding response from the server.
How do I go about this?
One advantage I see in this method is that I do not need to load jquery into the App

Comment: it's better to use axios.

Comment: I cannot use axios because there are many different querries initiated by users. I use php and mySqli for these querries. Even if axios will do these using another backend language, I do not wish to go through axios until I fully master reactjs